# Test checked state of checkbox from materializecss with cypress

Tags: checkbox, materialize, cypress

I have the following html generated by materializecss:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="new-spec-load-pet-checkbox" checked="">
    <span>Load Pet Example</span>
</label>
```

Now I want to test if the checkbox is checked or not, however, when I click on it, the checkbox itself changes, so it's working, but, the html does not. I assumer materializecss somehow overlays the checkbox with images.

How would I test that the checkbox has a certain state if it's not layed out in the html?

Comment: you can refer: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/check.html#Options

Comment: @Sree.Bh Indeed that works, although I have no idea how, it works. Thank you.